# How to Login into the Gmail account using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In order to login into the Gmail account using Jmeter, what are the parameters which I need to pass in the HTTP request. Can anybody please answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and the easiest way of learning what requests you need to mimic with JMeter in order to simulate this or that user action is just **recording** them. JMeter comes with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) which you can use to capture the requests and convert them into JMeter's [HTTP Request samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request).

---

Also be aware that JMeter provides [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) so if you need to fetch a email message (or several, or all) you can do it using the Mail Reader Sampler via [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) or [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) protocols. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) for more detailed exaplanation and sample configuration instructions for Gmail.